# How to specify installation of Firefox to use for watir-webdriver script execution

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

For testing purposes I have multiple Firefox installations/versions on one machine made by using [Utilu FF collection](http://utilu.com/UtiluMFC/).

If there`s

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :ff
```

in test script, it is automatically executed with oldest FF version which is 3.6.22 in my case. I was surprised, because I assumed that by default script will be executed in Windows default browser which is Firefox6 not Firefox 3.6.22.

How to specify which installation/version of Firefox must be used for Watir-webdriver test script execution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify a path to your firefox executable:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox.path = "/path/to/firefox.exe"
b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
```

Comment: It appears that it`s better to put path to Firefox in single quotes to avoid "Invalid escape character syntax" error.

Comment: I recieved errors when executing script C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.5.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:43:in `for': unknow
n driver: :Firefox (ArgumentError)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.5.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:81:in `for'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.3.2/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:35:in `initialize'

        from C:/Users/user/Documents/test1.rb:5:in `new'
        from C:/Users/user/Documents/test1.rb:5:in `<main>'

Comment: :firefox is case sensitive, therefore must be lowercase

Comment: @AlisterScott, similar to `Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox.path`, is there a way to modify the firefox parameters used when launched internally? Specifically I'm trying to remove `--no-remote`

Answer (score 2):

For those using `chromedriver` use:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = "path/to/chromedriver"
```

Answer (score 0):

For phantomjs:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::PhantomJS.path="/usr/bin/phantomjs"
```